# how to set sender name in inbox instead of sender name with Other name in java

Tags: java, email

i am using java mail API to send mail. i want sender name sender name to be other name in my example sender mail address is `from@example.com` but i want that to be other name in inbox 
here is my example

```
import java.util.Properties;  
import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  

public class send{  
 public static void main(String[] args) {  

  String host="smtp.gmail.com";  
  final String from="from@example.com";//change accordingly  
  final String password="12345";//change accordingly  

  String to="to@example.com";//change accordingly  

   //Get the session object  
   Properties props = new Properties();       
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
   props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
   props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); 

   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
    return new PasswordAuthentication(from,password);   
      }  
    });  

   //Compose the message  
    try {   
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));  
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
     message.setSubject("Test");  
     message.setText("hello");
    //send the message  
     Transport.send(message);  

     System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  

     } catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
 }  
}
```

can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InternetAddress` can be used like this: `InternetAddress(mail, alias)`, meaning you want to change

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
```

to

```
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, "Your Name"));
```

Now instead of `from@example.com` the recipient will see `Your Name` as the sender name.

Comment: where should i pass from Address in progaramm? already from address is there in my program

Comment: yeah but its coming like John Doe <from@example.com>. i want this to be John Doe <John Doe@example.com> and in inbox also sender name is coming like rom@example.com but not as John Doe@example.com

Comment: If you use `InternetAddress(mail, alias)`, then mail comes with `alias <mail>`, in example in my answer it would come as `Your Name <from@example.com>`. If you send a mail from `from@example.com` you cannot expect the receiver to see that it came from`your.name@example.com`. That would make no sense and make exploiting a piece of cake... If you want a receiver to see that mail came from `Your Name <your.name@example.com>`, then you have to do `InternetAddress("your.name@example.com", "Your Name")`

Comment: No problemo, amigo! :)

Comment: is it possible to remove senders mail id

Comment: I don't think so... :(